# Pytesseract OCR Bounding Box in group of two words

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, bounding-box

I am trying to use pytessearct to draw bounding boxes around words in a group of two. For example, it detects, "Bounding Box", by default pytessearct will draw two bounding boxes around each word. i.e "Bounding", "Box". But what is Want is a single bounding box around these two words.
So far my code

```
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    text = d['text'][i]
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top']
                           [i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```